# Pickle ignores __getstate__ on frozen dataclasses with slots

Tags: python, pickle, python-dataclasses

You are supposed to be able to override how `pickle` pickles an object with `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`. However, these methods are ignored when a dataclass specifies both `frozen=True` and `slots=True`.

```py
import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class Foo:
    bar: int

    def __getstate__(self):
        print("getstate")
        return {"bar": self.bar}

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        print("setstate")
        object.__setattr__(self, "bar", state["bar"])

b = pickle.dumps(Foo(1))
foo = pickle.loads(b)
```

The above script should print "getstate" and then "setstate". However, it prints nothing. It prints what I expect if I remove either `frozen` or `slots` or both. It is only the combination that fails.

I am on Python 3.11.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [considered a bug](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/104041#issue-1690829773) and was fixed starting in Python 3.11.4.